# Interpretation of logistic regression - interaction between predictors

Tags: r, regression, logistic, estimation, binomial-distribution

**Context**: Workbook question for my high-school statistics subject

An experiment was conducted where 30 parasitic worms of each sex were poisoned at each of five dosages, and the number of deaths were counted. This is the data that I read into R:

```
dosage <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 2)
sex <- factor(c("male","male","male","male","male",
                "female","female","female","female","female"))
deaths <- c(2, 6, 14, 20, 27, 0, 3, 9, 15, 18)
```

My task is to fit a logistic regression model, with the proportion of dead parasitic worms as the dependent variable and dosage as a predictor, allowing for a different response to the poison for both sexes, and make the model have no explicit intercept term.

I originally had this in R as:

```
summary(glm(deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage + sex,family=binomial, weights=rep(30,10)))
```

And here is the output:

```
Call:
glm(formula = deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage + sex, family = binomial, 
    weights = rep(30, 10))

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.43171  -0.38413  -0.01169   0.47773   0.98391  

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
dosage      1.0543     0.1265   8.332  < 2e-16 ***
sexfemale  -4.4138     0.5133  -8.599  < 2e-16 ***
sexmale    -3.4052     0.4457  -7.641 2.16e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 133.8908  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   5.4677  on  7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 42.24

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

However, when answering the sub-questions about p-values in the R output, one was asking about the interaction term between sex and dosage, which I'm not sure my model has since the coefficients are dosage, sexfemale and sexmale.

Did I interpret the question wrong (perhaps I should have * instead of + in my glm() function...), or am I not noticing something in my R output?

Comment: "allowing for a different response to the poison for both sexes" I would interpret this as an interaction term being needed.

Comment: @Roland could you point me in the direction of examples of this? I'm not exactly sure what the difference between this and just having an extra predictor of sex added? Would it involve something like `glm(deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage + dosage*sex, ...)`?

Comment: That model fulfills the requirements. The interaction term ensures that the slope of the function (in the logit space) can be different for the sexes. Personally, I usually don't omit intercepts, but your homework explicitly requires it. Parasites can die without poison.

Comment: @Roland when using `summary(glm(deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage + dosage*sex, family=binomial, weights=rep(30,10)))`, the only coefficients that come up are dosage, sexfemale, sexmale and dosage:sexmale. I'm assuming that last one is the interaction term we're talking about, but what about dosage:sexfemale? Why doesn't that appear?

Comment: You somehow changed the model after my last comment. I do not believe you should have the `sex` main effect in the model as that would be an intercept. Anyway, your last question is a FAQ. Google "treatment contrasts".

Comment: @Roland OK. So just to confirm, you mean `glm(deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage + sex + dosage*sex, ...)`?

Comment: No, I don't. AFAIU, the requirements are (1) no intercept and (2) different slopes for each sex. Your last proposed model meets requirement (2) but it contains intercepts. However, I'm not sure what your instructor would consider an implicit (as opposed to an explicit) intercept.

Comment: @Roland Does the `0` not eliminate the intercept? Are you suggesting `glm(deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage*sex, ...)`? Sorry, I'm really quite confused. By having no explicit intercept term, my instructor means to ensure that the model is forced through the origin.

Comment: If you include `sex` as a main effect and not only in an interaction term, you have specified an intercept. I just don't know if your teacher considers that an "explicit intercept". I'm not familiar with that term. Note that `*` and `:` are not the same.

Comment: Further research indicates that `first:second` indicates the set of terms obtained by taking the interactions of all terms in `first` with all terms in `second`, whereas `first*second` indicates the cross of `first` and `second`. 
This leads me to believe that my model should be `glm(deaths/30 ~ 0 + dosage + dosage:sex, …)`?

Comment: Yes, that model has two slopes and no intercept. It makes the hard assumption that the parasites don't die without poison. In real-world research I would not make that assumption.